# Webpack 1 with transform-loader?brfs on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, fs, pdfkit

I am using the library `pdfkit` which uses `fontkit` which has hardcoded `require('fs')` in it, no matter if you use it on client or server.

Now the project is in React, using Webpack 1 for packaging. The regular overcoming of the problem is using the following webpack config.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /node_modules\/(pdfkit|fontkit|png-js|linebreak|unicode-properties|brotli)\ //,
      loader: "transform-loader?brfs"
    },
  ],
},
```

This works great on MacOS, Linux and in Docker containers **but** now working on Windows 10 workstations. I could not find anyone having the same problem.

**Edited** the following does not resolve completely the case

I managed to overcome it by the following fake library hardcoded in the `node_modules/fs/index.js` file:

```
class fsClass {
  readFileSync (file) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve('fake readFileSync: ' + file));
  }
}

const fs = new fsClass();

module.exports = fs;
```

The project compiles it that way and is working but still I do not think this is the right decision. Any help/ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have reached only one resolving of the problem. As suggested here:
https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/wiki/How-to-compile-standalone-PDFKit-for-use-in-the-browser

```
$ npm install browserify brfs
$ npm install pdfkit 
$ node_modules/.bin/browserify --standalone PDFDocument node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js > pdfkit.js
```

Then copy the file in the src folder and include `pdfkit` from there. The things work perfectly. The result is - precompiled library in the repo and a Webpack warning for that.

Still will be glad if anyone suggests a better decision